# How to use URLFOR() in Lightning web component of salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am new to file handling in Salesforce. I am currently working on downloading files of all records of a custom object. I read many blogs and found there are a couple of ways to do it. I decided to go with the shepherd URLFOR() approach as it seems simple and easy but now I have all the ContentDocumentId in a string format and I don't know how to use URLFOR() in the Lightning web component. Every blog and post gives the URL but I was not able to find how to use it once it is made. Is it used in Apex or HTML pages?

Can someone guide me?

Here is the URL I have formed

`{!URLFOR('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' & StringOfContentDocumentIds &'?')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expression syntax used in VisualForce and in Aura component.

You're talking about Lightning Web Component (known as LWC) so this syntax is not valid.
I would advise to use the standard approach which is [using the navigation service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_open_files).

If you really want to use the `shepherd` trick, then you need to write something like this:

#### fileDownload.js

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'

export default class FileDownLoad extends LightningElement {
  contentVersionIds = []

  get urlOfContentDocumentFile () {
    return `/sfsites/c/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/${this.contentVersionIds.join('/')}?`
  }
}
```

#### fileDownload.html

```html
<template>
  <a href={urlOfContentDocumentFile} target="_blank">Download</a>
</template>
```

Please note that I changed the url to add `/sfsites/c` before as you seems to talk about a community. If it's not, then you can just remove that part.

P.S: I don't know how you get the list of contentVersionIds so I didn't cover that part.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answered my question. I got the list of contentVersionIds already done.